# TSPLIB Name of locations

Tags: traveling-salesman

is there a source for the names of the locations contained within TSPLIB
at http://www2.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/.

For illustration purposes it would be nice to know where point 31 is on the 
Berlin52 instance.

Thanks

Robert
ps: yes I googled it - however I could not find anything except for ulysses 16.
very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the data comes from [this website](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/). The data set filenames seem to align.